# pyspark - read json files

Tags: json, pyspark

I am trying to read this json files.

```
{
    "data": [{
            "id": "c1",
            "type": "corporate",
            "tenor": "10.3 years",
            "yield": "5.30%",
            "amount_outstanding": 1200000
        },
        {
            "id": "g1",
            "type": "government",
            "tenor": "9.4 years",
            "yield": "3.70%",
            "amount_outstanding": 2500000
        },
]}
```

**Code**
    df = spark.read.option("multiline", True).json("sample_input.json")
    df.select(col("data")).show()

However this reads everything into single column. Is there a way I can apply schema using `id`, `type`, `tenor` and other columns?

Comment: after loading the data with your existing code, just run `df = df.selectExpr('inline(data)')`

Comment: @jxc Thanks. it solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

If you try to load multi-line json with permissive mode then you can able see dataframe correctly,

```
df = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").option("mode", "PERMISSIVE").json("sample_input.json")
df.printSchema()

root
 |-- data: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- amount_outstanding: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- tenor: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- yield: string (nullable = true)
```

If you remove the data element from json and try to load then it will load correctly like this.
Json content:

```
[{
            "id": "c1",
            "type": "corporate",
            "tenor": "10.3 years",
            "yield": "5.30%",
            "amount_outstanding": 1200000
        },
        {
            "id": "g1",
            "type": "government",
            "tenor": "9.4 years",
            "yield": "3.70%",
            "amount_outstanding": 2500000
        }]
```

Ouput Schema:

```
df = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").option("mode", "PERMISSIVE").json("sample_input.json")
df.printSchema()

df.printSchema()
root
 |-- amount_outstanding: long (nullable = true)
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- tenor: string (nullable = true)
 |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- yield: string (nullable = true)
```

In both option you have correct data frame once it is correctly populated extract and transform data the way you want.